# Change button image source WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, button, controltemplates

I have a button with a template.

I would like to dynamically change the image source from the code behind.

Here is my code:

```
<Button Height="48" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="playSequence" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="49" Click="PlaySequenceButton_Click" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,0,0">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                <Image Name="PlayImage" Source="Play.png" Width="45" Height="41" Stretch="Fill"/>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
   </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

When I type this code:

```
PlayImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Pause.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

`PlayImage` is not recognized.

Is there any way to change the button's image source that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might prefer to set the image by means of the Button's `Content` property in a Style like this:

```
<Button ...>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border ...>
                            <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                   Width="45" Height="41" Stretch="Fill"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <BitmapImage UriSource="Play.png"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Now you could simply change the image by setting the `Content` property:

```
playSequence.Content = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Pause.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: Thanks. That helped. By the way, is there any way to give the button back its `click effect`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by click effect.

Comment: Before I added the image to the button, the button had a 3D visual behavior when it was clicked. Now the button is static, I can see only the image, even if I click it. There is no indication that the button was clicked. Is there any way to 'restore' that visual effect when I click the button?

Comment: That is because the default Button Style is a lot more complex than what we have here. See [Button Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328.aspx) to get an overview and pay special attention to the different Visual States.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `FindName` method of a `FrameworkTemplate`:

```
playSequence.Template.FindName("PlayImage", playSequence)
            .SetValue(Image.SourceProperty, 
                      new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Pause.png", UriKind.Relative)));
```